# Insert data from one input into two mysql columns

Tags: php, mysql, insert, str-replace, multiple-columns

I have a simple insert.php formular that got created by Dreamweaver CS5. I want to be able to enter my News headline in this formular into the column "news_headline" in my database and then automatically add this headline into the column "news_slug" with lowercase and space converted to minus.

So if I enter "This is a headline" into the Headline input field in my form, it would enter "This is a headline" into my "news_headline" column and  it would add "this-is-a-headline" into my "news_slug" column.

I got the following code so far:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$news_headline = $_POST['news_headline'];
$news_slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $news_headline);

  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_news (news_headline, news_slug) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['news_headline'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['news_slug'], "text"));
```

The Basic Rest

```
    mysql_select_db($database_Jahrhundertkomet, $con);
    $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $Jahrhundertkomet) or die(mysql_error());}
    mysql_select_db($database_Jahrhundertkomet, $con);
    $query_Jahrhundertkomet = "SELECT * FROM tbl_news";
    $Jahrhundertkomet = mysql_query($query_Jahrhundertkomet, $con) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_Jahrhundertkomet = mysql_fetch_assoc($con);
    $totalRows_Jahrhundertkomet = mysql_num_rows($con);
    mysql_free_result($con);
    ?>
    <form method="post" name="form1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
    <table align="center">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap align="right">News_headline:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="news_headline" value="" size="32"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Datensatz einfügen"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
</form>
```

But now, when I enter a headline in the code it gets the error: Column 'news_slug' cannot be null. What do I have to change to enter my input from news_headline into news_slug with the transforms?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace whitespaces for scores, you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):
Also you are using `$_POST['news_slug'];` which doesn't receive anything because there's no input named `news_slug` in your form.

Try this:

```
 $news_headline = $_POST['news_headline'];
 $news_slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $news_headline);
```

And place those lines just after this one:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
```

Comment: Yes, I deleted the input news_slug in my form, because I want this to be added automatically, thats the point... I tried your code above but it still says, that columns news_slug cannot be null. So somewhere I have to specify, that this transformed news_headline gets entered into the news_slug column

Comment: What values you get when you print the variables before the query?

Comment: And which is the order of the codes you posted?? "The new Code" should be executed before the query.

Comment: Here you can see the whole code with the right chronological order:
http://jsfiddle.net/hn45J/
The print command is not working. Or I do it wrong

Comment: I have updated the answer. As i told you, you should place "the new code" before the query.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I put the code on top of the query now but it still says that the column news_slug cannot be null. I still have to specify somewhere, that the entry in my "news_headline" form should be put into the "news_headline" AND the "news_slug" columns (with the str_replace)

Comment: Do you have any ideas maybe? Would be highly appreciated :)